# Android JDBC/JTDS connection to MSSQL

Tags: android, sql-server, jdbc, database-connection, jtds

So I've looked at probably about 10 other threads, mostly here, but also other places and tried everything I can think of and still no go. I need to make a simple connection to my MSSQL server in my Android app. I'm aware of the security implications of this! :)

So I've included jtds-1.2.7.jar (some mentioned the 1.3.0 didn't work with Android) and I'm trying with this code (I have tried several other constallations of code, but no luck so far):

Imports:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver;
```

Actual code:

```
Connection conn = null;
try {
String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
String connString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://10.0.0.27:1433;encrypt=false;user=test;password=test;instance=SQLEXPRESS";
String username = "test";
String password = "test";
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString,username,password);
```

LogCat tells me it fails at 
`conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString,username,password);`

---

```
04-01 08:46:07.540: W/Error connection(13554): null
04-01 08:46:07.700: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(13554): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

---

I downloaded an app that lets you connect to a MSSQL server and run queries. In that app it connects just fine to 10.0.0.27 with test/test so it's not a connectivity issue as far as I see it.

Comment: i have the sam error could you solved it?